# Escape sequence with backslash for NSURL path

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am doing a simple GET request to a remote server with the help of AFNetowkrking.
The path for that call with **curl** is: `/api\?member\=11\&type\=forum` and responds with OK200.

But this path in iOS and AFnetworking 2 gets a warning - the backlash is not recognized "unknown escape sequence" and removed from the path, thus the server returns 404.

How can I add this escape sequence to the string so that the server responds with no error?

Comment: You don't need/want those backslashes in iOS.

Comment: The server returns 404 if I send request without them, yeah these escapes are really annoying.

Comment: Check the base URL, perhaps showing us both (replace the domain, if needed).

Comment: You need the forward slash `/`, but not the backslashes `\ `. The full URL should look something like `https://server.domain/path/to/api?member=11&type=forum`

Answer (score 1):

It is quite rare to have backslash in this type of URL, but if it is needed, add nother one, so there are 2 backslashes. like: `member\\=11\\&`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[myString stringByReplacingString:withString:` to replace @"\" by @""